# How to get the dataframe row, and when the column reaches a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['@1','A',2],['@2','A',1],['@3','A',4],['@4','B',1],['@5','B',1],['@6','B',3],['@7',
'B',3],['@8','C',4]],columns=['id','channel','people'])

   id channel  people
0  @1       A       2
1  @2       A       1
2  @3       A       4
3  @4       B       1
4  @5       B       1
5  @6       B       3
6  @7       B       3
7  @8       C       4
```

and I want to take out some rows , and the sum of rows can't greater than a value

so my code is ,

```
num = 5           # the sum of column name 'people' should <= num
list = []

for i in range(0,len(df)) :
    num = num - df.loc[i,'people']
    if (num > 0):
        list.append(df.loc[i].copy(deep=True))
    elif (num == 0):
        list.append(df.loc[i].copy(deep=True))
        break
    else:
        list.append(df.loc[i].copy(deep=True))
        list[i]['people'] = num + df.loc[i,'people']
        break
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=df.columns)

   id channel  people
0  @1       A       2
1  @2       A       1
2  @3       A       2
```

But I think I write too complicated ,

Can you suggest a better algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Your example does not match the explication, as I understand it the algorithm should stop at row 1. Or should the solution include as many peoples from the last row so that the final sum is 5?

Comment: the answer should include as many peoples from the last row ,and the sum should <= 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['@1','A',2],['@2','A',1],['@3','A',4],['@4','B',1],
                   ['@5','B',1],['@6','B',3],['@7','B',3],['@8','C',4]],
                  columns=['id','channel','people'])

>>> df
Out[]:
   id channel  people
0  @1       A       2
1  @2       A       1
2  @3       A       4
3  @4       B       1
4  @5       B       1
5  @6       B       3
6  @7       B       3
7  @8       C       4

# Get rows including the one that goes beyond the threshold
new_df = df[df.people.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0) < 5].copy()

>>> new_df
Out[]:
   id channel  people
0  @1       A       2
1  @2       A       1
2  @3       A       4

# Limit value of last row to match threshold condition
new_df.loc[:, 'people'].clip_upper(5 - new_df.people.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0),
                                   inplace=True)

>>> new_df
Out[]:
   id channel  people
0  @1       A       2
1  @2       A       1
2  @3       A       2
```

#### Walkthrough

Extract the rows

```
# Get cumulative sum for `people`
>>> df.people.cumsum()
Out[]:
0     2
1     3
2     7
3     8
4     9
5    12
6    15
7    19
Name: people, dtype: int64

# Shift by 1 to include border value
>>> df.people.cumsum().shift(1)
Out[]:
0     NaN
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     7.0
4     8.0
5     9.0
6    12.0
7    15.0
Name: people, dtype: float64

# Fill `NaN` with 0 and create `bool` array  with `< 5`
# this gives the index of rows to be extracted
>>> df.people.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0) < 5
Out[]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: people, dtype: bool
```

Then to limit last value to stay less or equal to threshold, `clip_upper` is used together with the shifted cumulative sum of `df_new.people`.
Using `clip` instead of just `5 - new_df.iloc[-1].people.sum()` allow to take into account the case where the total sum of `people` will not reach `5`.

**Note** beware that `inplace` argument for `pandas.clip_upper` is new from version `0.21`

---

**EDIT**

Fix `clip_upper` not working properly and `pandas` `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning.

Comment: I got error with this line ('numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'clip_upper')
                                   
new_df.loc[new_df.index[-1], 'people'].clip_upper(5 - new_df.iloc[:-1].people.sum(),inplace=True)
'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'clip_upper' , let me try to modify

Comment: I modify to new_df.loc[new_df.index[-1], 'people'] = min(new_df.loc[new_df.index[-1], 'people'],5 - new_df.iloc[:-1].people.sum()) , this can work thanks again @FabienP

Comment: but why you got no error at this line , clip_upper should use in pandas.Series , isn't it? @FabienP

Comment: You're right @RelaxZeroC, I think I tried on a `Series` and did not checked properly the last version where it was applied on a single value. Fixed this issue, and fixed `pandas` warning too by creating `new_df` as a copy of sliced `df`. It should work as-is now, can you confirm?

Comment: I have try the modify answer , it's work fine. thanks for your help,let me clear thinking. @FabienP